# jquery validate plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

In my case name and id's of form are different and names are of format data[password]   so thsi is the solution that i found on net and it works

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{               
    var passwd = $("#old-password").attr("name");
    var $params = {debug:false, rules:{}, messages:{}};

    $params['rules'][passwd]    = {"required": true, "maxlength": 100};  
    $params['messages'][passwd] = {"required": "Please Enter Old Password ",'maxlength':'Old Password should not exceed 100 characters'};

    $("#GamerAccountSettingsForm").validate($params);
});
```

This outputs a ***label with class error*** but this is what i want it to do. **If** there is a ***div with class error-message*** next to this input field it should show error inside it else it needs to append a div with class error-message to the input field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the errorPlacement options for this  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options

And if I am correct, this should work;

```
$params['errorPlacement'] = function(error, element) 
{
   if($(element).next("div.error-message"))
   {
       $(element).next("div.error-message").html(error.html());
   }
   else
   {
       divError = $("<div class='error-message'>" + error.html() + "</div>");
       divError.insertAfter(element);
   }
};
```